# How to sort in OCAML ordering by two elements

Tags: sorting, ocaml

I have a a struct like this:

```
type leitura =
{
  nome : string;
  notaMax : int;
  media : float;
};;
```

And a list created from reading the elements in a file.

Then I have:

```
List.iter (
  fun leitura_l -> (
    match leitura_l with
    | [] -> print_string("> sem leitura <\n")
    | _ ->
      let leitura = get_leitura leitura_l in
      printf "%-8s" leitura.nome;
      printf "%-8d" leitura.notaMax; 
      printf "%-8f" leitura.media;
  )
) list_estudantes;;
```

I need to print the list of students ordered by notaMax, first, and when it is equal, ordered also by media.

So, I want to get somethinh like this:

```
Nome      Nota Máx.    Média
Jorge        15         13
João         13         12
Mário        13         11
```

Answer (score 1):

Split up your code. Write a function which sorts them and then write a function which prints the sorted array. Seems like a task you have to fulfill on your own. You can make it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't give the type of `list_estudantes`. It looks from your code like it is `leitura list list`. This is because you run `List.iter` over this value, but in each iteration (handled by the function `fun leitura_l -> ....`) you match the parameter against list patterns.

But somehow I don't think this is right, as it would mean that each student has several `leitura` records.

My suspicion is that `list_estudantes` is just a list (not a list of lists), and that your inner function should look more like this:

```
fun leitura ->
    printf "%-8s" leitura.nome
    (* And so on *)
```

The only other thing that seems to be missing is the sorting of the list.  You can sort a list using `List.sort`, where you supply a function that compares two values of type `leitura`.

The comparison function looks something like this:

```
let my_compare a b =
    if a.notaMax < b.NotaMax then -1
    (* And so on *)
```

As @gapsong points out, your code would be much easier to read and understand if you wrote separate functions to sort and to print the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jeffrey. I'me really new in Ocaml and I'm not undestanding how to do it. Can you help me a little bit more? I have the type leitura, and a list with the names of the students, and their best grade (int) and mean (float). I would like to order that list by grade and by mean, and then print it, but I'm not being able to do it.